# How to deal with many routes in flask

Tags: python, flask

in flask we have the usual

```
@app.route()
```

we all know about that but what if you have many routes (lets say 60) in theory how would you organize them?
a single views.py file wont cut it and organizing them by category wont cut it either because we will have 8 main pages and 52 user posts so how would you deal with such a problem?
NOTE: this is only a theory so don't say that i am stupid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend checking out an article called [Structure of a Flask Project](https://lepture.com/en/2018/structure-of-a-flask-project) taken from this Python Bytes [podcast episode](https://pythonbytes.fm/episodes/show/102/structure-of-a-flask-project).

It talks about a functional based structure vs an app based structure (which you commonly find in Django).  These are two approaches you can take.  These are just recommendations and Flask is very flexible so you can do whatever you want.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add enough context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so that if the link dies, your Answer is still an answer. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.** Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Thanks @Makyen for your suggestions.  This makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

For '52 user posts' and similar page routes you should use [routes with variables](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#variable-rules), 
like so

```
@app.route('/post/<int:post_id>')
def show_post(post_id):
    # show the post with the given id, the id is an integer
    return 'Post %d' % post_id
```

I hope this will make it clear for you